# Memory monitoring on Mac or Linux

Tags: linux, macos, memory, memory-profiling

Is there any tool to monitor application memory over time and see it as a graph?

For instance, in Windows there is a perfmon. I can easily configure the processes I want to monitor and the resolution and see the graph over time.

Is there something similar in Mac or Linux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to script it yourself with `gnuplot` and `bash`:

```
$ cat memory-plot.pg
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
reset
set terminal dumb 120,40
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
set xlabel "time"
set ylabel "RSS, KB"
set title "Process RSS over time."
set grid
set style data linespoints
plot "< tail -n 90 rss.txt" using 1:2 title "RSS"

$ pid=`pgrep Xorg`; clear; while sleep 1; do (printf "%(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)T "; ps -ho rss,cmd -p $pid) >> rss.txt; printf "\033[0;0H"; gnuplot memory-plot.pg; done
```

Outputs a live chart in the terminal:

```
                                                   Process RSS over time.

  105500 +-+--+-----+----+----+-----+----+----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+----+----+-----+----+----+-----+--+-+
         +          +         +          +          +          +         +          +          +         +          +
         |          :A        :          :          :          :         :          :          :        RSS +--A--+ |
         |          :|        :          :          :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          :|      A : -A     A :          :          :         :          :          :         :          |
  105000 +-+.........|......|..A.|....A|..........................................................................+-+
         |          :|      | :| |    || :          :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          :|      |||  |    || :   AA     :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          :|      |||  |    || :   ||     :          :         :          :          :         :          |
  104500 +-+.........|.....|.|...|....||....A..|..................................................................+-+
         |          :||    | A:  |    || :  |  |    :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          :||    |  :  |   | | :  |   |   :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          :||    |  :  |   | | :  |   A   :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          :||    A  :  |   | | :  |   |   :          :         :          :          :         :          |
  104000 +-+.........||.AAA.......|..|..|...|...|.................................................................+-+
         |          :||A      :   |  |  |: |    |   :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          :|||      :   | AA  |: |    |   :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          | |       :   |A    |: |     |  :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          | A       :   ||    |: |     |  :          :         :          :          :         :          |
  103500 +-+........|.............||....|..|.....|................................................................+-+
         |          |         :   ||    |: A     |AAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA-AA-AAAAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAAA         |
         |          |         :   |     |: |     || :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          |         :   |     |:|      A  :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          |         :   A     AAA         :          :         :          :          :         :          |
  103000 +-+........|.............................................................................................+-+
         |          |         :          :          :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          |         :          :          :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          |         :          :          :          :         :          :          :         :          |
  102500 +-+........|.............................................................................................+-+
         |          |         :          :          :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         |          |         :          :          :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         AAAAAAAA-AAA         :          :          :          :         :          :          :         :          |
         +          +         +          +          +          +         +          +          +         +          +
  102000 +-+--+-----+----+----+-----+----+----+-----+----+-----+----+----+-----+----+----+-----+----+----+-----+--+-+
       11:49      11:49     11:49      11:49      11:49      11:49     11:50      11:50      11:50     11:50      11:50
```

Comment: Thanks. What should I change in the script to see time interval of 24 hours and not last 2 minutes?

Comment: @Sash That `tail` command takes last 90 samples. Change that number.